# replacing backslashes with forward slashes in actionscript

Tags: regex, flash, actionscript-3

```
var aText:String = "C:\\folder\\folder\\file";
var filterVal:String = aText.toLowerCase().replace( /\//g, '/');
trace( aText );
trace( filterVal );
```

results as:

```
C:\folder\folder\file
c:\folder\folder\file
```

this code was based on [this site](http://blog.acrespo.mediajux.com/using-regex-replace-forward-slashes) and nascent regex skills.

What am I doing wrong?  Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you are doing it wrong, what you seem want \is:

```
var filterVal:String = aText.toLowerCase().replace( /\\/g, '/');
```

The initial and ending '/' delimit the Regular Expression. What is inside (\\) is what you are searching for. Since it's a backslash, you need to escape it.

Comment: sorry, I should have matched title with code.  i will remedy that now.

Comment: great, just edited my response removing the other option. Also clarified a bit how the RegExp is written.